# Hypernym for the products from trees

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, hypernyms

I want to know a hypernym I can use to call products from trees. For example, mangoes, coconuts, oranges, bananas.

I want to use this word in a context like below sentences.

> 1. Mangoes are .... of mango trees.
> 2. Bananas are .... of banana trees.

Comment: Nuts are also the product of trees.

Comment: And cinnamon and maple syrup are both products of trees, but are neither fruits nor nuts.

Comment: I think the O.P. needs to clarify whether we are talking about fruits and nuts alone, or about lumber, saps, leaves, and bark as well (some of which are used in teas, syrups, extracts, or herbal remedies).

Comment: Banana's don't grow on trees, The banana plant is the world's largest perennial herb - from [here](http://www.chiquitabananas.com/worlds-favorite-fruit/banana-answers-information-faqs.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mangoes, coconuts, oranges and bananas are fruits.

Comment: Can I say "Mangoes are fruits of mango trees"?

Comment: You can, but it's so obvious that I wonder why you would want to. (In any case, you would have to say _the fruits_).

Comment: There are a few cases where it's not so obvious (like, "The acorn is the fruit of the oak tree"). But whether or not _fruits_ is a complete hypernym depends on @PeterShor's question above; namely, _Does maple syrup count_? Or, for that matter, _eucalyptus leaves_?

Comment: @J.R.It's obvious that mangoes are the fruits of mango trees. That's all.

Comment: Can I also say "Fruits are the fruits of trees"? It sounds strange to say this but I want to make sure that I understand that word the way you explain it. :)

Comment: @code4eight. You can, but I don't know why you would want to.

Answer (score 3):

*Fruit* is a word that not only means edible but anything from a supply. Example usage:

> He is the fruit of my loins.

Comment: Not all fruits are edible; some are poisonous. Generally speaking, from a horticultural perspective, [fruit](http://www.wordnik.com/words/fruit) means "seed-bearing" (which is why a tomato is a fruit, as are cucumbers, pumpkins, and peppers).

Comment: And not all products of a supply are called "fruit", even metaphorically. Sexual reproduction is the primary context in which this term is used as a euphemism. The analogy is that the man's "seed" falls into the fertile woman, who "bears fruit". Ideas, and products incorporating them, are also sometimes called "fruit" of the group that developed them. Virtually nothing else is referred to using this metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

Collins licenses 'tree husbandry' as well as 'forest management' for *forestry*:

forestry [ˈfɒrɪstrɪ] n

1. (Life Sciences & Allied Applications / Forestry) the science of planting and caring for trees
2. (Life Sciences & Allied Applications / Forestry) the planting and management of forests

After examining other definitions, I'm sure the term *forestry* can be extended to include *the obtaining of products from trees*.

We can then use the term *forestry products* to cover all relevant products, whether simply obtained (fruits, nuts), obtained with more art (latex, timber) or made from more basic products (plywood, tyres) - no matter how primitive or sophisticated the harvesting / refining / manufacturing processes that are involved.

At http://www.envirothon.org/pdf/CG/forest_products.pdf , *The Almost Everything In The Whole Wide World Made From Trees ...* is a very informative article.

Answer (score -1):

Mangoes are the yield of mango trees.

Bananas are the yield of banana trees.